# Windows 10 - Folder Picker 'Save as' or 'Open' not working

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad

The folder picker/dialog when using 'Save as' or 'Open folder' are not showing. And this occurs across all apps. First noticed using Word, but noticed this occurred also with PowerPoint or Excel. Tried opening Chrome and Firefox, using right mouse click and selecting 'Save as' nothing happens as well.

The weird thing is that File Explorer works without problems, only the folder pickers are not working.

Already tried:

- Starting in safe mode
- Disabling all services and restarting

In both cases the problem still persists. Can't figure out what might be causing this.

System info:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
- Lenovo Thinkpad

If anyone has any ideas to solve please let me know.

Comment: I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: OK.. I just deleted the last thing I had to say.  It appears that Microsoft had this problem prior to 1903 related to high contrast settings.  It is possible that it is back.. or that your specific configuration was not fixed.  If you are using high contrast, disable it and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Although the May 2020 Update was not available via the Windows Update (Thinkpads were having problems with this update, see [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht510448#thinkpad) if your device is compatible), I ended up manually updating to build 2004, and solved the problem.